# How do I modify stored procedure so it can process request based on request mode?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

We wrote a stored procedure that uses SQL Server's send_dbmail feature to send emails to potential users with details of their registrations.

This stored procedure works great.

The only issue we currently have is that users will also like to request a copy of their forgotten password.

I can write another stored procedure to handle this? However, is there a way to modify the stored procedure below so that it recognizes the mode of the request?

For instance, currently a user creates an account and details of the account are stored in `tblLogin` table.

This stored procedure grabs the account info, stores it in Notifications table and finally email details of this account to the user who just registered.

Similarly, we would like the same stored procedure to process when a user uses the `Forgotten Password` feature to request a password.

How do I modify the stored procedure send email based on what is being requested?

In other words, if the data stored in `tblLogin` table is for a `new account` creation, the stored procedure should grab it and send an email to user with details.

If data is for `forgotten password`, the stored procedure should only email that info as well.

Is this possible with the stored procedure below?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetRegistrationInfo] 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE Register_Cursor CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT 
            LoginId, FullName, email, Password
        FROM 
            [tblLogin]
        WHERE 
            ProcessedFlag = 'No'
        ORDER BY 
            LoginId DESC

    OPEN Register_Cursor

    DECLARE @LoginId INT
    DECLARE @fullname NVARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @email NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @password NVARCHAR(20)

    -- Get the current MAX ID 
    DECLARE @mailID as INT 

    -- Start reading each record from the cursor. 
    FETCH Register_Cursor INTO @LoginId, @fullname, @email, @password

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
    BEGIN 
        --set @mailID = (SELECT max(mailID) from Notifications) Not needed; let's auto-genereate the id
        INSERT INTO [Notifications] (mailContent, LoginId, FullName, email, Password, sender, Sent) 
        VALUES ('This is a computer generated email message. 
Please DO NOT use the REPLY button above to respond to this email. 

Dear '+@FullName+': 

Thanks for registering to take the Training!

Below are details of your registration information:

Your UserName is: '+@email+'. 

Your Password is: '+@password+'. 

Once you have retrieved your login information, please click the link below to get back to Training login screen and begin to begin to enjoy the benefits of membership. 


http://servername/training/

Regards, 
The Registrations & Elections Office.', @LoginId, @FullName, @email, @Password, 'NoReply@serverdomain', 'No') 

        FETCH Register_Cursor INTO @LoginId, @FullName, @email, @password
    END

    CLOSE Register_Cursor  
    DEALLOCATE Register_Cursor
END

BEGIN
    DECLARE MAIL_CURSOR CURSOR FOR
        SELECT mailid, sender, mailcontent
        FROM [Notifications]
        WHERE Sent = 'No'

    DECLARE @mail1 INT
    DECLARE @sender NVARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @content1 NVARCHAR(4000) 

    OPEN MAIL_CURSOR

    FETCH MAIL_CURSOR INTO @mail1, @sender, @content1

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @email = @email + ';' + Email
        FROM [Notifications]
        WHERE sent = 'No'

        -- exec sp_send_cdontsmail @mail1, null,null,@content1,null
        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
                  @profile_name = 'The Office', 
                  @recipients = @email, -- your email
                  --@blind_copy_recipients = @email,
                  @subject = 'Your Account Details',
                  @body = @content1;

        -- Update the record in Notifications table where Sent = 'No'.
        UPDATE [Notifications] 
        SET Sent = 'Yes' 
        WHERE Sent = 'No' AND mailid = @mail1

        UPDATE [tblLogin] 
        SET ProcessedFlag = 'Yes' 
        WHERE ProcessedFlag = 'No' AND LoginId = @LoginId 

        FETCH MAIL_CURSOR INTO @mail1, @sender, @content1
    END

    CLOSE MAIL_CURSOR
    DEALLOCATE MAIL_CURSOR
END
```

Comment: Funny, this looks related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668750/how-do-i-get-this-code-to-grab-records-from-one-table-and-insert-into-another-us). Sure, you can add a parameter to indicate the function or functions (`@F = 'FORGOT_PASSWORD,GET_MILK'`). You have to ask yourself if it will become an unmaintainable mess or a logical grouping of functionality. Since you are storing and emailing passwords as cleartext, there doesn't seem to be a reason to separate functionality for security reasons. You could pass in a template message and let the sproc substitute: "Pass is {PWD}".

Comment: thank you sir. Yes, they are related in a way. However, I actually solved that by substituting ModifiedDate with ProcessFlag. I should have deleted that one. Not sure I understand @F-Forgot_Password,GET_MILK

Comment: Instead of `ProcessedFlag` or `ModifiedDate` just use `EmailTemplate`. You can make each one unique: `Thanks for signing up. Your username is {Username} and password is {Password}.`, `Sorry to hear you forgot your password. We've generated a new one for you: {Password}. You do remember your username, right?`. Use `REPLACE()` to replace all occurences of the snippets, e.g. '{FullName}', with the appropriate value and then send it. Templates could be stored in another table and just referenced to save space.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I’m missing something here but this looks like you only need one IF - ELSE statement that will send one message in one case and another message otherwise…

Comment: thank you for your response.

I guess my biggest confusion is *how* to tell the stored proc to recognize when to process new accounts vs when to process forggoten password request.

Remember that in the case of New Accounts, data actually gets stored in tblLogin table.

With forgotten password request, nothing gets stored in any table.

So, I am not sure what to do to trigger a connection with the stored proc.

I hope this makes sense.